# Nested routes content not showing up content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom

Below code is the entry point

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <AppProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/admin/*' element={<Admin />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<App />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </AppProvider>
</React.StrictMode>
```

I have Child routes under `App.js` and `Admin.js`, but routes under `Admin` is not routing as expected at the same time `App.js` routes are working accordingly.

Code for Admin.js is below

```
<div>
  <ASideMenuNav />
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/admin/product' element={<AProductsInfo />} />
    <Route path='/admin/offers' element={<AProductOffers />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
```

Output is as shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2DeM.png)

Problem I am facing here is that when I click on any navigation menu its URL is changing but the content of the particular React component is not showing up.

Someone please tell me what am I missing. Is there something wrong with coding logic?

Answer (score 0):

Descendent routes in the `Routes` component will have their paths built ***relative*** to the parent route. If the parent route path is `"/admin/*"` then the current paths are `"/admin/admin/product"` and `"/admin/admin/offers"`. The solution is to remove the `"/admin"` path prefix on the descendent routes.

```
<div>
  <ASideMenuNav />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/product" element={<AProductsInfo />} />
    <Route path="/offers" element={<AProductOffers />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
```

Alternatively the `Admin` component could render an `Outlet` component and the routes could be converted to nested routes in the `App`.

```
<div>
  <ASideMenuNav />
  <Outlet />
</div>
```

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <AppProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/admin' element={<Admin />}>
          <Route path="product" element={<AProductsInfo />} />
          <Route path="offers" element={<AProductOffers />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' element={<App />}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </AppProvider>
</React.StrictMode>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Drew Reese for your suggestion. It worked as you said.